# Laravel Homestead command not working on Mac

Tags: laravel, homestead

I installed composer and this works ok.

I installed the homestead command using this command:

```
composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0"
```

I change this on my .zshrc file

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Everything works ok, apparently. But when I run the `homestead` command I get this:

```
cd:cd:13: no such file or directory: /Users/my_user/Laravel/Homestead
```

What can I do? Help please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a newbie mistake.

The problem was that I have an alias homestead. So the system run alias before the command homestead.